# Is it possible to create an ndarray of ndarray? (python 2.7, numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

For example,

```
t = np.ndarray((10), dtype='void')
a = np.ndarray((10), dtype='float') 

for b in range(10):
    a[b] = b

t[0] = a
```

Is there a way I can do this?

I am getting an error:

> ValueError: data-type with unspecified variable length

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does this relate to Unix & Linux?

Comment: Python runs under linux. Other people post python questions here.

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to make a 2-D array?

Comment: EdChum,

I'm asking how to create an ndarray of ndarray. ndarray is a type of array in numpy.

Comment: Well...it is possible to create a 2-D array; but filling a `dtype=void` with an array of `float` will lead to `numpy` not understanding what you want to achieve. So, what you want to achieve, is mistifying `numpy`, mistifying us and mistifying you yourself as well.. :) Do you mean `t = np.ndarray((10), dtype=np.ndarray)`?

Comment: "Do you mean t = np.ndarray((10), dtype=np.ndarray)?"

yes, however that returns an error:

"TypeError: data type "np.ndarray" not understood"

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.types.html, it seems numpy.ndarray only support scalar data types.

Comment: Well, mnielson somehow created an ndarray of ndarry. How did he do it?